# LINQ: Associations not functioning correctly for use with innerjoins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, associations, inner-join

Can anyone help, I have been using linq2sql with great success using my associations (foreign keys) to provide inner joins etc...

for example this, works great, the color is stored in a table called Color which has association so i pick it up via Color.Description - Excellent.  Same for StructureType its actually an association so i pick it up via the structureType association and the field Description which is in the StructureType table

```
     from v in Houses
     select new 
     {
        Id = v.Id,
        Color = v.Color.Description,
        StructureType= v.StructureType.Description,
        Price = v.StructureGroup.StructureGroupTariffs. // doesn't provide anything more only Any, All etc
}
```

The problem being is that Price i am trying to link, so houses has a Association to StructureGroup which has a association to StructureGroupTariffs but i don't get any more options..

StructureGroupTariffs in an Interlinking table that links StuctureGroup to Tariffs,

I actually did a test here with the interlinking table in Linq and it works! like so

```
        from g in StructureGroupTariffs
        select new 
        {
           Price = g.Tariff.Price
        }
```

So i am a little confused, why (see above) this

```
        Price = v.StructureGroup.StructureGroupTariffs.
```

only returns methods like Any, All etc but not the association....

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StructureGroupTariffs is an EntitySet not an EntityRef, i.e. it contains many objects rather than a single object. You can't extract the 'many' into the 'single' that you are assembling in your query.

EDIT

I suspect that your House table has a StructureGroup and that there is a Tariffs table, in between is a StructureGroupTariffs table that holds FK references to each of the other tables allowing there to be many tariffs for each structure group (irrespective of whether there actually are many tariffs). Hence Linq using an EntitySet to refer to the StructureGroupTariffs.

Comment: thanks Lazarus, so what are my options, yes you are correct i notice (using linqpad) that it returns an entityset. Do i have to do a specific join then in the linq, using a where or something??

Its true to get a single record i must pass in v.IdTariff and v.StructureGroupId which I have ...

Can you ellaborate? if i do pass in these 2 ids i notice in linq that it returns only 1 record but of course without these it returns about 30 :-)

Comment: Yes you are exactly right with you edited answer, this is exactly how it is organized

Comment: a small correctin  on v. i have IdTariff but StuctureGroupId isn't on Houses its on StructureGroupTariff and Tariff but linq doesn't give me access to the tariffID on either table so i can't include in my where

Comment: You would have to select a single StructureGroupTariff, i.e. Price = v.StructureGroup.StructureGroupTariffs.Single().  or .First(). or .Select(sgt => sgt.somefield == somevalue).